# Правка документов онлайн

Tags: php, wordpress, google-docs

Добрый день!
Такая задача. Заказчик хочет загружать бланки документов на сайт (там вордпресс стоит) так, чтобы пользователи могли их заполнять и отправлять со своими данными на сервер.

Сложность в том, что бланки у заказчика всегда разные, то есть, я не смогу отобразить их все средствами html. Ему нужно именно загружать их.
Возможно ли вообще такое? Как вариант рассматривала google docs, но там совместное редактирование документа, а нужно просто заполнение полей. 
Знаете ли вы какие-то решения данной задачи?

Comment: Тут диллема - либо приучить заказчика создавать "бланки" в ВП, либо отдавать их на скачивание. Либо же писать парсер "разных" бланков в неизвестном формате.
Хотя у гуглодока есть вроде бы настройки разрешающие править только определённые поля. В аналоге экселя во всяком случае это должно быть

Comment: спасибо) в гуглодоках, как я поняла, нельзя сделать так, чтобы правки документов сохранялись только для определенного пользователя. Может, плагины какие есть... поизучаю. Я уже думаю над тем, чтобы они сами создавали бланки. Множество проблем решилось бы

Comment: Я с гуглодокам не работал, но по-моему можно. По сути это как бэ аналог МС офиса (и тп), только в онлайне. И если разрешено, то любой может сохранить в свой акк изменённый документ. Другое дело - будет ли это удобно пользователям. Я бы, напр, вряд ли пользовался таким.

Comment: А по поводу ВП - есть масса плагинов для составления форм. Но это вряд ли будет удобно клиенту. А чтобы предложить более удобные варианты - надо видеть что это за бланки, какие поля и тп. В общем случае может быть будет достаточно создать кастомный тип постов с произвольным полями. Или же изменяемые поля вставлять шорткодами, выводя у них элементы формы (типа конструктора в CF7, но только попроще в работе и как аналог поста)

Comment: Надо в гуглодоках динамически создавать новый документ из бланка и давать пользователю доступ только к его версии документа.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать